# AWS EMR Parallel Mappers?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-emr

I am trying to determine how many nodes I need for my EMR cluster. As part of best practices the recommendations are:

(Total Mappers needed for your job + Time taken to process) / (per instance capacity + desired time) as outlined here: http://www.slideshare.net/AmazonWebServices/amazon-elastic-mapreduce-deep-dive-and-best-practices-bdt404-aws-reinvent-2013, page 89.

The question is how to determine how many parallel mappers the instance will support since AWS don't publish? https://aws.amazon.com/emr/pricing/

Sorry if i missed something obvious.

Wayne

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To determine the number of parallel mappers , you will need to check this documentation from EMR called Task Configuration where EMR had a predefined mapping set of configurations for every instance type which would determine the number of mappers/reducers.
http://docs.aws.amazon.com/emr/latest/ReleaseGuide/emr-hadoop-task-config.html

**For example :** Lets say you have 5 m1.xlarge core nodes. According to the default mapred-site.xml configuration values for that instance type from EMR docs, we have

```
mapreduce.map.memory.mb = 768
yarn.nodemanager.resource.memory-mb = 12288
yarn.scheduler.maximum-allocation-mb = 12288 (same as above)
```

You can simply divide the later with former setting to get the maximum number of mappers supported by one m1.xlarge node `= (12288/768) = 16`

So, for the 5 node cluster , it would a max of `16*5 = 80` mappers that can run in parallel (considering a map only job). The same is the case with max parallel Reducers(30). You can do similar math for a combination of mappers and reducers.

So, If you want to run more mappers in parallel , you can either `re-size` the cluster or reduce the `mapreduce.map.memory.mb`(and its heap `mapreduce.map.java.opts`) on every node and restart NM to

To understand what the above mapred-site.xml properties mean and why you do need to do those calculations , you can refer it here : 
https://hadoop.apache.org/docs/r2.7.2/hadoop-yarn/hadoop-yarn-common/yarn-default.xml

*Note* : The above calculations and statements are true if EMR stays in its default configuration using `YARN capacity scheduler` with `DefaultResourceCalculator`. If for example , you configure your capacity scheduler to use `DominantResourceCalculator`, it will consider VCPU's + Memory on every nodes (not just memory's) to decide on parallel number of mappers.

Comment: Thank you so much. That was definitely hidden down there in the weeds.

Comment: Sure. Glad it helps.