# MapReduce: Increase number of concurrent mapper tasks

Tags: java, hadoop, mapreduce, jvm, amazon-emr

I am using AWS EMR to run a map reduce job. My input set contains 1 million files each of around 15KB. Since input files are very small, so this will lead to a huge number of mappers. So, I changed s3 block size to 20KB and used 5 r3.2xlarge instances but number of concurrent tasks running is still just 30. Shouldn't the job run more number of concurrent mappers now after reducing the block size or even after reducing block size, memory taken by each mapper is still same?

How can I limit the memory usage of each mapper or increase the number of concurrent mapper tasks? The current expected completion time is 100hours, will combining these files to lesser number of bigger files, like 400MB files, increase the processing time?

Answer (score 2):

Reducing Block size can increase the number of mappers required for a particular job , but will not increase the parallel number of mappers that your cluster can run at a given point nor the memory used for those mappers.

> used 5 r3.2xlarge instances but number of concurrent tasks running is
>   still just 30

To find the parallel maps/Reducers that a Hadoop 2 EMR cluster can support , please see this article [AWS EMR Parallel Mappers?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41454796/aws-emr-parallel-mappers)

**Ex:  r3.2xlarge * 5 core's :**

```
mapreduce.map.memory.mb 3392    3392
yarn.scheduler.maximum-allocation-mb    54272
yarn.nodemanager.resource.memory-mb     54272
```

Once core-node can have 54272/3392 = 16 mappers .

So, a cluster can have a total of 16*5 = 80 mappers in parallel.

So , if your job spins up like 1000 mappers , cluster can launch 80 mappers with that preconfigured memory and heap on your nodes and other mappers will be simply Queued up.

If you want more parallel mappers, you might want to configure less memory (based on that math) and less heap  for mapper.

Answer (score 0):

What you are looking for is CombineFileInputFormat .

Do remember map slit size by default = HDFS block size by default. Changing one will not affect the other.

Please follow the link : http://bytepadding.com/big-data/map-reduce/understanding-map-reduce-the-missing-guide/