# aws emr add step limitation; Can I run steps in parallel?

Tags: amazon-web-services, hadoop-yarn, sqoop, amazon-emr

I have bunch of SQOOP jobs that I would like to launch via EMR add-step.
My existing on-prem method is to run them in parallel till YARN resources are exhausted.

I am noticing that when I create bunch of add-step for individual SQOOP job, they are sequential in nature.
Question: Is there a a way for me to run my add-steps in parallel? (limitation: I don't have access to the master node to launch application directly.)

I am sure I am missing something trivial here; as it sounds like a massive limitation that parallel processing can't happen in EMR using add-step.

..Manas

*PS: I can run them as multiple thread but then I won't get the logs for distinct application that would get launched against YARN.*

Comment: I'm not sure about the parallel job stuff, but If you don't have SSH access to the master node and you wish to execute a bash command, you can do so via AWS SSM's RunCommand

Comment: Sorry that won't work. My question is essentially regarding achieving functional parity of on-prem using add-steps.

Comment: TL;DR: no :) A nice explanation in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43121382/running-steps-of-emr-in-parallel) answer

Comment: I don't think [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43121382/running-steps-of-emr-in-parallel] [this link] covers the actual problem. My cluster is configured with fair scheduler. The problem I am facing is that add-step does not even submit the jobs in parallel. AWS EMR instead queues them and sends them sequentially. So even though my job each takes 5 % of the total resources, the cluster is under utilized as jobs don't run in parallel. The problem candidate here is add-steps go through a queue of its own. (different from Yarn queue)

Answer (score 0):

With EMR 5.28.0, one can run up to 256 steps concurrently. 
[EMR Add up to 256 steps](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55410084/aws-emr-add-step-limitation-can-i-run-steps-in-parallel)

It is also possible to add more than 256 steps.
[Add more than 256 steps](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/emr/latest/ManagementGuide/AddMoreThan256Steps.html)

fyi - at the time of writing this response, it seems that there is a limit of adding 10 steps per second when using Step functions. My understanding is that EMR itself doesn't have any such restriction and one should be able to add as many steps to it, assuming cluster has resources to accept it.